# Rails Authorization error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, authorization

I'm currenty trying to integrate the [rails-authorization](http://code.google.com/p/rails-authorization-plugin/) plugin into a rails application. I've followed through the installation and setup steps but each time I try to use the

```
permit "role"
```

or

```
permit? "role"
```

functions, I get an error thrown up along the lines of 'const missing, User#RolesUser' which doesn't appear to have any use in the plugin at all (It uses a Role model and a RolesUsers table). Has anyone else come across this issue at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found that this seems to be a bug using this plugin with rails 2.2.2. Also found that changing all references of

```
:roles_users
```

to

```
:role_users
```

in the plugin lib files (specifically the object_roles_table.rb file), the migration generated and in the Roles model generated then the plugin works correctly.